# Запятая перед обстоятельством: в начале романа(,) в Петербурге

Tags: пунктуация

> Таким читатель застает героя в начале романа(,) в Петербурге, на Гороховой улице, где он живет со своим слугой Захаром.

Нужна ли запятая, взятая в скобки?

По моему мнению, нет, так как начало романа и Петербург совершенно разные места.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тоже думаю, что это не уточнение, потому что когда? в какой момент чтения? в каком месте романа? и где? в каком географическом месте? - совершенно разные "где?".